# Does a return statement end a method?

Tags: java, methods, boolean

Let's say I have a method, for instance, the one I'm working on is a boolean *Empty* method, that simply returns false if the list (technically it's a stack using linked lists) is empty, and returns true if it has values.

I have an if statement that returns false if the first value of the list is null (considering it's a stack) and returns true if it has values.
Here is that method in my code:

```
public boolean empty(){
       if(list.getFirst() == null){
          return false;
          }
          else{
          System.out.println("Stack has values.");
       }
    return true;
 }
```

my question is, if I have determined that the list is empty and return false, will the method end there? Or, in other words, does a method stop doing things once it gets a return message?

Comment: Yes it will end there...did you try it?

Comment: Yes, it will end the method once a value is returned.

Comment: @brso05 I did have the method built one way, and it worked fine, I was just looking to see if there were some ways I could make it a little better.

Comment: Did you do *any* research before asking this question? E.g. googling `java return` will find you the [The Java™ Tutorials - Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html), and reading the first 3 lines will answer your question: *A method **returns to the code that invoked it** when it [...] reaches a return statement*

Answer (score 1):

A method mostly stops doing things once you hit a return statement.  One exception is that if you have a try block with a finally clause, that finally clause will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

It just exits the method at that point. Once the `return` is executed, the rest of the code in the method won't be executed and control will be passed to the parent.

eg.

```
public boolean test(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return true; 
    }
    else if (n == 2) {
        doStuff();
        return false;
    }
    doOtherStuff();
}
```

Note that the compiler is smart enough to tell you some code cannot be reached:

```
if (n == 3) {
    return;
    customFunction(); //compiler error here
}
```